# Evaluar un "non-object" en condicional IF() LARAVEL

Tags: laravel

He mejorado un poco en laravel, pero aun me falta , estoy intentando de hacer algo que ni siquiera se si es posible (espero que si)  el Punto,   quiero evaluar  si mi relacion arroja un objeto nulo  para con un if  indicar que relacion utilizar para evitar este error
hasta el momento e intentado esto :

```
//si la persona posee contrato, los datos son llamados desde la tabla contratos 

            @forelse($ausentismo as $ausentismo)
              <?php
                if(is_object($ausentismos->persona->contrato)){ 
                    $costo = (($ausentismo->persona->contrato->salario)/30)/8;
                    $Total_costo = $diff * $costo;
                    $f_inicio = $ausentismo->persona->contrato->fecha_inicio;
                    $salario = $ausentismo->persona->contrato->salario;
                    $eps=$ausentismo->persona->afiliación->EPS;

                }else // si no, los datos son llamados desde la tabla retirado
                    $costo = (($ausentismo->persona->retirado->salario)/30)/8;
                    $Total_costo = $diff * $costo;
                    $f_inicio = $ausentismo->persona->retirado->inicio;
                    $salario = $ausentismo->persona->retirado->salario;
                    $eps = $ausentismo->persona->retirado->EPS;
              ?>
```

los datos de la tabla persona no se eliminan, los datos de la tabla contrato si, pero se crea un resumen en la tabla retirado. se que los modelos están bien, por que sin retirados, el código funciona, pero con retirados,  da el error "Trying to get property 'salario' of non-object", intente con un "

```
 if(is_null($ausentismos->persona->contrato))"
 if(is_object($ausentismos->persona->contrato))"
 if($ausentismos->persona->contrato =='null'))"
```

pero no realiza la evaluación y arroja el error "Trying to get property 'variable' of non-object"

Gracias por la ayuda.

Comment: Has intentado con `property_exists()`? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.property-exists.php

Comment: Gracias por responderme, intente con  `property_exists()` pero daba negativo a todas las peticiones (creo que lo hice mal), y el opcional no me sirve, por que estoy haciendo la evaluación desde una vista,    lo solucione evaluando el estado desde `$ausentismos->persona`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si solo ocurre una de las dos cosas puedes guardarlos en una variable

```
//Toma el primero, si no existe, el segundo
$pe = $ausentismos->persona->contrato ?? $ausentismos->persona->retirado;

//comprobamos que exista la persona
if($pe){
    $costo = (($pe->salario)/30)/8;
    $Total_costo = $diff * $costo;
    $f_inicio = $pe->inicio;
    $salario = $pe->salario;
    $eps = $pe->EPS;
}
```

en cuanto a las plantillas

```
@if($pe)
    //en caso de null toma toma un campo vacio ('')
    <p>{{$costo ?? ''}}</p>
@else
    <h1>Persona no existe</h1>
@endif
```